# Динамическое обновление содержимого в контейнере в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, gui, controller, fxml

Предположим у нас есть 100 вопросов. У каждого вопроса разное количество вариантов ответов. Все эти вопросы занесены в базу данных, в которой помечено сколько в каждом вопросе этих вариантов ответов. Как мне сделать так, чтобы динамически менять содержимое контейнера, например, было 3 варианта ответа в вопросе, в следующем вопросе их будет 4, как мне добавить этот вариант ответа ***не меняя сцену***, как-нибудь сделав это из контроллера или изменив fxml-файл?

Comment: Что у вас получилось до сих пор?

Comment: **Ничего** не получилось... Мне надо хотя бы понять, как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, в этой же сцене, появилась еще одна совершенно другая кнопка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример создания элементов (без прямого доступа к "контейнеру")

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button button = new Button("Start button");
        button.setOnAction(new CreateAnswerHandler());

        Pane container = new VBox(button);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(container, 300, 500));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

Обработичк:

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class CreateAnswerHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

    public Button createAnswerButton() {
        Button button = new Button(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        button.setOnAction(new CreateAnswerHandler());
        return button;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        if ( event.getSource() instanceof Button ) {
            Button bSource = (Button) event.getSource();

            Parent parent = bSource.getParent();
            if ( parent != null && parent instanceof Pane ) {
                Pane pane = (Pane) parent;
                pane.getChildren().add(createAnswerButton());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Можно вас спросить? А зачем мы делаем подобного рода проверки: if ( event.getSource() instanceof Button ) { ... } и  if ( parent != null && parent instanceof Pane ) { ... } .

Comment: Что бы избежать ClassCastException. Т.к. класс является public то "потенциально" использовать его могут не только Button расположенные на Pane.